# luckybackup-pkexec (as root) fails in Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3

Tags: automation, qt

I tested the failure in the terminal of its app's source folder to see the errors. The question is, what is needed to re-install, Qt? because the app has been purged and reinstalled twice.

```
root@LMC203DT:/usr/bin# luckybackup-pkexec
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
root@LMC203DT:/usr/bin#
```